# need a requeue at n method for ConcurrentQueue<>

Tags: c#, .net

I need a requeue at the nth element where n is defined by an ordered key.

```
 ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, SomeClass>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, SomeClass>>();


 queue.RequeueByOrderedKey(key, element)
```

OR

```
 queue.RequeueN(index, element)
```

... since it looks necessary to implement this myself, I'm considering something based on public

```
  class Class1 : KeyedCollection<K,V>{}

   it'd be nice to have Class1 : OrderedKeyedCollection<K,V>{}
```

Here's some code that I did.  I'll put it here for comment, and then probably move it to be an answer.  Probably haven't handled the concurrency stuff properly yet.

```
    public class QueueExt<TK, TV> : SortedList<TK, TV> {

        #region Constructors

        public QueueExt(Func<TV, TK> getKey = null) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        private Func<TV, TK> GetKey = null;

        public QueueExt(int capacity, Func<TV, TK> getKey = null)
            : base(capacity) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        public QueueExt(IComparer<TK> comparer, Func<TV, TK> getKey = null)
            : base(comparer) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        public QueueExt(int capacity, IComparer<TK> comparer, Func<TV, TK> getKey = null)
            : base(capacity, comparer) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        public QueueExt(IDictionary<TK, TV> dictionary, Func<TV, TK> getKey = null)
            : base(dictionary) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        public QueueExt(IDictionary<TK, TV> dictionary, IComparer<TK> comparer, Func<TV, TK> getKey = null)
            : base(dictionary, comparer) {
            GetKey = getKey;
        }

        #endregion

        public TV Dequeue() {
            lock (this) {
                var first = this.ElementAt(0).Value;
                this.RemoveAt(0);
                return first;
            }
        }

        public void Requeue() {

            if (GetKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key getter lamda must not be null");

            lock (this) {
                var key = this.ElementAt(0).Key;
                var actualkey = GetKey(this.ElementAt(0).Value);
                if (!actualkey.Equals(key)) {
                    this.Enqueue(this.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Enqueue(TK key, TV item) {
            this.Add(key, item);
        }
        public void Enqueue(TV item) {
            if (GetKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key getter lamda must not be null");
            var key = GetKey(item);
            this.Add(key, item);
        }

        public TV Peek() {
            return this.ElementAt(0).Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx). You create your indexable queue and make it implement [IProducerConsumerCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147%28VS.100%29.aspx). I show how to use `BlockingCollection` this way in my article [Customizing Blocking Collection](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=822). I use a stack in the article, but you could easily enough replace the stack with your indexable queue.

An alternative might be a concurrent priority queue. You can build a simple one with a heap and a lock. See my article [A Generic Binary Heap](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789). You'll need to add the synchronization.

Comment: Does the underlying collection need to be concurrent?  i.e. IProducerConsumerCollection implements IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable.  Thanks for the tip.  I'm not sure I'd even have explored this given the name that it has.  It just didn't sound relevant, yet makes sense once you think about what it means.  How did you come across it?

Comment: The underlying collection must be concurrent if you're going to use it from multiple threads. Of course, it could implement concurrency by using a lock. I came across `BlockingCollection` because I was looking for ... well, a blocking collection--something that would let me put a limit on the number of things that can be put into a queue.

Comment: looks like I can key an underlying dictionary with anything I like -- so I could remove from the underlying, and then push in again via Blocking.  About to test this.

Comment: drat.  No "Peek" or conditional Take available.

Comment: `Peek` on a concurrent data structure would be a rather dangerous thing, don't you think? After all, you might peek at something and before you decide to do anything with it, another thread could come by and steal it from you. See my edited response.

Comment: yep... was wondering about that.  didn't like the lock + test lamdas that would be needed to step around that.  A weighted heap looks to be perfect for this situation.  Thanks for answer!

Comment: do you know of a concurrent implementation?

Comment: I don't know anything about the C5 collections. Also, it's not difficult to make my example heap concurrent. You just need to add a `lock { ... }` around the code in the `Insert`, `Peek`, and `RemoveRoot` methods. That will perform quite well unless you're hitting the data structure really hard.

Answer (score 1):

No, it' s not possible, cause it's a essense of `queue`, you can not have key or index access to it. Use a `List<>` for this.

Comment: I'm looking for a hybrid of some sort.  Clearly a queue model could allow this.  Say I'm queuing to go in to a night club, then ladies can jump the queue entirely (i.e. talk to be bouncer or fein VIP status), or join friends who are already queuing.  The essence is what you define it to be.

Comment: @sgtz: I repeat, the `Queue` it *not designed* for index access, or for ordering. It's just different type of structure. You need some FIFO structure but with index *and* orded access (lloking on the post) , so using the simple implementation over `List<T>` is exactly what you need.

Comment: There is no reason a queue could not support this. Unfortunately, it happens not to have such a feature but it could.

Comment: @usr: this is FIFO structure definition, that is. It's just design issue. Want index access? Want order? Use `List`.

Comment: The `Queue<T>` class is implemented with an array as an expandable [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Accessing any element in an array by index is an O(1) operation, and that is exactly what the `Queue<T>` class does to get/set the head and tail elements. In fact, the `Queue<T>` class even has a `T GetElement(int i)` method, which can look up any element in the queue by index — unfortunately, for whatever reason, this is an inaccessible internal method.